# Acceptable synonym for *very good* in this scientific context: "... X is a *very good* technology..."

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing a scientific paper, and I want to say the following:

> The development of DC transmission dates to the
>   1930’s and has proven to be **a very good** technology since the first
>   major installations in 1954

But the syntax `a very good technology` seems to me to be a bit too uncommon to appear in a scientific paper.  Is there any other word that fits in its place and conveys the same (or a similar) idea?   I was thinking about `a reliable technology` even if it doesn't mean 100% the same thing, but it sounds more scientific-y.

Comment: reliable doesn't mean 100% the same thing as "very good", but I think "very good" doesn't really say much. You're just saying the technology is good... very good.... great... excellent or whatever. I don't know, I feel that isn't really saying much. Maybe if you go with "successful". Obviously the good part is inferred because if something is successful it's usually good.

Comment: Come on! You need to work out what *you* mean by 'very good'. No-one can double-guess what you mean.  Choosing an alternative just because it 'sounds scientific-y' seems, er, unscientific to me...

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful tips and suggestions! Indeed, I was thinking "very good" in terms of "successful" .

Comment: There is no way of answering this unless you explain exactly what it is you're trying to say.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some options you can consider:

"a widely used technology": minimal change, but not exactly the same meaning

"an important innovation": does not use the word "technology"

"a technology of significant importance": a bit redundant and wordy, but can serve the purpose here

"an important technological breakthrough": use only if it's really a "breakthrough"